# Invalid or unexpected token ID3 when importing mp3 in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, import, mp3

I keep running into this error when trying to dynamically import a mp3 file.

[image]

I'm importing it this way.

[image]

So I don't understand where the ":1 ID3" is coming from. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I wasn't able to solve the problem, but I did find a work around for now. Instead of fetching the mp3 file in the server, I fetched it from the client by creating a static folder in the server to hold all the music files.

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/serving-static-files-in-nodejs

Comment: You seem to have a transpilation issue, which has 2 ways to be solved: either you modify your webpack config, to be able to handle audio files, or you replace `await import()` by `require`

Comment: Ah ok thank you, I'll look into that. I'll add an edit if I find something.

Comment: Why not just read the mp3 file with the node.js "fs" module?